# Replicate IBM Tivoli LDAP Server

Tags: ldap, replication, tivoli

We had an environment with two IBM Tivoli LDAP servers with IBM Tivoli LDAP configured in peer to peer mode also utilizing NLB.

One our machines crashed and we installed a fresh OS on the machine with empty IBM Tivoli LDAP server.

Now we want to replicate working Tivoli LDAP server to this new server. Can somebody please tell us how can we configure this peer-to=peer replication again with old and new LDAP server without losing any data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either export a ldif file and import it to the new server or use a Tivoli Directory Server (TDI) to move data between the servers. TDI can also be used afterwards to keep the two directory servers in sync.